# Getting ORA-01031: insufficient privileges after confiduring sonarqube to connect to an Oracle 12.01.02 DB

Tags: sonarqube

I have setup up a linux installation of Sonarqube 5.4 connecting to an Oracle 12.01.02 DB.

After starting sonarqube, I get the following error messages on the web interface:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges 
: CREATE SEQUENCE projects_seq START WITH 10000 from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record /connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:183:in `execute'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/oracle/adapter.rb:134:in `create_table'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2231:in `send'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `method_missing'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
from jar:file:/usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:228:in `create_table'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/db/migrate/001_initial_schema.rb:22:in `up'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
from jar:file:/usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:282:in `migrate'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365:in `migrate'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491:in `migrate'
from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
from org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:576:in `ddl_transaction'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in `migrate'
from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `migrate'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:66:in `upgrade_and_start'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/lib/database_version.rb:77:in `automatic_setup'
from /usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:306:in `(root)'
from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in `load'
from file:/usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in `(root)'
from file:/usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in `load_environment'
from file:/usr/local/sonarqube-5.4/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79:in `load_environment'

at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98)
at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
at org.sonar.server.platform.RubyRailsContextListener.contextInitialized(RubyRailsContextListener.java:35)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
: CREATE SEQUENCE projects_seq START WITH 10000
```

I can see in the database that the tables Projects and Schema_migrations are added.
I can also delete the tables using the same credentials defined for sonarqube.

Here is a listing of my sonar.properties file:

```
# Property values can:
# - reference an environment variable, for example sonar.jdbc.url= ${env:SONAR_JDBC_URL}
# - be encrypted. See http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/settings-encryption.html

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DATABASE
#
# IMPORTANT: the embedded H2 database is used by default. It is recommended for tests but not for
# production use. Supported databases are MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQLServer.

# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=XXX

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
# sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092


#----- MySQL 5.x
# Only InnoDB storage engine is supported (not myISAM).
# Only the bundled driver is supported. It can not be changed.
# sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance


#----- Oracle 11g/12c
# - Only thin client is supported
# - Only versions 11.2.x and 12.x of Oracle JDBC driver are supported
# - The JDBC driver must be copied into the directory extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/
# - If you need to set the schema, please refer to http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5000
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbt16-vip.xxx.com:1521/tplm


#----- PostgreSQL 8.x/9.x
# If you don't use the schema named "public", please refer to http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5000
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar


#----- Microsoft SQLServer 2008/2012/2014 and SQL Azure
# A database named sonar must exist and its collation must be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS)
# Use the following connection string if you want to use integrated security with Microsoft Sql Server
# Do not set sonar.jdbc.username or sonar.jdbc.password property if you are using Integrated Security
# For Integrated Security to work, you have to download the Microsoft SQL JDBC driver package from
# http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774
# and copy sqljdbc_auth.dll to your path. You have to copy the 32 bit or 64 bit version of the dll
# depending upon the architecture of your server machine.
# This version of SonarQube has been tested with Microsoft SQL JDBC version 4.1
# sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true

# Use the following connection string if you want to use SQL Auth while connecting to MS Sql Server.
# Set the sonar.jdbc.username and sonar.jdbc.password appropriately.
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar
#----- Connection pool settings
# The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated
# at the same time, or negative for no limit.
# The recommended value is 1.2 * max sizes of HTTP/HTTPS pools. For example if both HTTP and
# HTTPS ports are enabled with default sizes (50, see properties sonar.web.http.maxThreads
# and sonar.web.https.maxThreads) then sonar.jdbc.maxActive should be 1.2 * (50 + 50) = 120.
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=50

# The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the
# pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit.
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5

# The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool,
# without extra ones being created, or zero to create none.
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2

# The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there
# are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before
# throwing an exception, or <= 0 to wait indefinitely.
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000

#sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
#sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000



#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WEB SERVER

# Web server is executed in a dedicated Java process. By default heap size is 768Mb.
# Use the following property to customize JVM options.
#    Recommendations:
#
#    The HotSpot Server VM is recommended. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx768m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Disabled when value is -1.
#sonar.web.port=9000


# Recommendation for HTTPS
#    SonarQube natively supports HTTPS. However using a reverse proxy
#    infrastructure is the recommended way to set up your SonarQube installation
#    on production environments which need to be highly secured.
#    This allows to fully master all the security parameters that you want.

# TCP port for incoming HTTPS connections. Disabled when value is -1 (default).
#sonar.web.https.port=-1

# HTTPS - the alias used to for the server certificate in the keystore.
# If not specified the first key read in the keystore is used.
#sonar.web.https.keyAlias=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the server certificate from the
# specified keystore file. The default value is "changeit".
#sonar.web.https.keyPass=changeit

# HTTPS - the pathname of the keystore file where is stored the server certificate.
# By default, the pathname is the file ".keystore" in the user home.
# If keystoreType doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.keystoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified keystore file. The default
# value is the value of sonar.web.https.keyPass.
#sonar.web.https.keystorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of keystore file to be used for the server certificate.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the keystore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the keystore type is used (see sonar.web.https.keystoreType).
#sonar.web.https.keystoreProvider=

# HTTPS - the pathname of the truststore file which contains trusted certificate authorities.
# By default, this would be the cacerts file in your JRE.
# If truststoreFile doesn't need a file use empty value.
#sonar.web.https.truststoreFile=

# HTTPS - the password used to access the specified truststore file. 
#sonar.web.https.truststorePass=

# HTTPS - the type of truststore file to be used.
# The default value is JKS (Java KeyStore).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreType=JKS

# HTTPS - the name of the truststore provider to be used for the server certificate.
# If not specified, the list of registered providers is traversed in preference order
# and the first provider that supports the truststore type is used (see sonar.web.https.truststoreType).
#sonar.web.https.truststoreProvider=

# HTTPS - whether to enable client certificate authentication.
# The default is false (client certificates disabled).
# Other possible values are 'want' (certificates will be requested, but not required),
# and 'true' (certificates are required).
#sonar.web.https.clientAuth=false

# HTTPS - comma separated list of encryption ciphers to support for HTTPS connections.
# If specified, only the ciphers that are listed and supported by the SSL implementation will be used.
# By default, the default ciphers for the JVM will be used. Note that this usually means that the weak
# export grade ciphers, for instance RC4, will be included in the list of available ciphers.
# The ciphers are specified using the JSSE cipher naming convention (see
# https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html)
# Example: sonar.web.https.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
#sonar.web.https.ciphers=

# The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time.
# When this number has been reached, the server will not accept any more connections until
# the number of connections falls below this value. The operating system may still accept connections
# based on the sonar.web.connections.acceptCount property. The default value is 50 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.maxThreads=50
#sonar.web.https.maxThreads=50

# The minimum number of threads always kept running. The default value is 5 for each
# enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.minThreads=5
#sonar.web.https.minThreads=5

# The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing
# threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.
# The default value is 25 for each enabled connector.
#sonar.web.http.acceptCount=25
#sonar.web.https.acceptCount=25

# TCP port for incoming AJP connections. Disabled if value is -1. Disabled by default.
#sonar.ajp.port=-1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ELASTICSEARCH
# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options of Elasticsearch process
#    Recommendations:
#
#    Use HotSpot Server VM. The property -server should be added if server mode
#    is not enabled by default on your environment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html
#
#sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# Same as previous property, but allows to not repeat all other settings like -Xmx
#sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# As a security precaution, should be blocked by a firewall and not exposed to the Internet.
#sonar.search.port=9001

# Elasticsearch host. The search server will bind this address and the search client will connect to it.
# Default is 127.0.0.1.
# As a security precaution, should NOT be set to a publicly available address.
#sonar.search.host=127.0.0.1


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# UPDATE CENTER

# Update Center requires an internet connection to request http://update.sonarsource.org
# It is enabled by default.
#sonar.updatecenter.activate=true

# HTTP proxy (default none)
#http.proxyHost=
#http.proxyPort=

# NT domain name if NTLM proxy is used
#http.auth.ntlm.domain=

# SOCKS proxy (default none)
#socksProxyHost=
#socksProxyPort=

# proxy authentication. The 2 following properties are used for HTTP and SOCKS proxies.
#http.proxyUser=
#http.proxyPassword=


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGGING

# Level of logs. Supported values are INFO(default), DEBUG and TRACE (DEBUG + SQL + ES requests)
# sonar.log.level=TRACE

# Path to log files. Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Default is <installation home>/logs
# sonar.path.logs=logs

# Rolling policy of log files
#    - based on time if value starts with "time:", for example by day ("time:yyyy-MM-dd")
#      or by month ("time:yyyy-MM")
#    - based on size if value starts with "size:", for example "size:10MB"
#    - disabled if value is "none".  That needs logs to be managed by an external system like logrotate.
#sonar.log.rollingPolicy=time:yyyy-MM-dd

# Maximum number of files to keep if a rolling policy is enabled.
#    - maximum value is 20 on size rolling policy
#    - unlimited on time rolling policy. Set to zero to disable old file purging.
#sonar.log.maxFiles=7

# Access log is the list of all the HTTP requests received by server. If enabled, it is stored
# in the file {sonar.path.logs}/access.log. This file follows the same rolling policy as for
# sonar.log (see sonar.log.rollingPolicy and sonar.log.maxFiles).
#sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=true

# Format of access log. It is ignored if sonar.web.accessLogs.enable=false. Value is:
#    - "common" is the Common Log Format (shortcut for: %h %l %u %user %date "%r" %s %b)
#    - "combined" is another format widely recognized (shortcut for: %h %l %u [%t] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}")
#    - else a custom pattern. See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#AccessPatternLayout
#sonar.web.accessLogs.pattern=combined


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OTHERS

# Delay in seconds between processing of notification queue. Default is 60 seconds.
#sonar.notifications.delay=60

# Paths to persistent data files (embedded database and search index) and temporary files.
# Can be absolute or relative to installation directory.
# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
#sonar.path.data=data
#sonar.path.temp=temp


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DEVELOPMENT - only for developers
# The following properties MUST NOT be used in production environments.

# Dev mode allows to reload web sources on changes and to restart server when new versions
# of plugins are deployed.
#sonar.web.dev=false

# Path to webapp sources for hot-reloading of Ruby on Rails, JS and CSS (only core,
# plugins not supported).
#sonar.web.dev.sources=/path/to/server/sonar-web/src/main/webapp

# Elasticsearch HTTP connector, for example for KOPF:
# http://lmenezes.com/elasticsearch-kopf/?location=http://localhost:9010
#sonar.search.httpPort=-1
```

With select * from session_privs I can see the following privileges:

SET CONTAINER

CREATE PROCEDURE

CREATE VIEW

CREATE TABLE

ALTER SESSION

CREATE SESSION

Regarding to the Oracle admin this includes: 
update table
delete table
select table

Do anyone have an idea what to look after for solving the issue?

Is there an option to capture the SQL statements send to the DB to get the failing SQL statement?

Thanks and Regards

Martin

Answer (score 0):

the issue could be solved by giving the folowing acces rights to the Oracle DB for the Sonar user:

SET CONTAINER

CREATE INDEXTYPE

CREATE OPERATOR

CREATE TYPE

CREATE TRIGGER

CREATE PROCEDURE

CREATE SEQUENCE

CREATE VIEW

CREATE CLUSTER

CREATE TABLE

ALTER SESSION

CREATE SESSION

Kind Regards
Martin